# What will be the Id of the orders from LastRealOrder and LoadByIncrementId

Tags: magento2, sales-order

I wanted to know what will be the output of the following.

`$LastorderId = $this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder()->getIncrementId();`

`$orderId = $this->_orderFactory->create()->loadByIncrementId($LastOrderId)->getIncrementId();`

if the `$LastorderId` I get is `000000016`. What will be `$orderId` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After your update both output will be same

**000000016**

The output will be following of these

```
$LastorderId = $this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder()->getIncrementId();
```

**000000016**

Then the most probably the entity id will be

```
$orderId = $this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder()->getEntityId();
```

**16**

but it is not always the same. it changes sometime.

Comment: What will be the output of $orderId ?

Comment: 16 depend on you order table *sales_order* entity_id.

Comment: I am asking the output of this `$orderId = $this->_orderFactory->create()->loadByIncrementId($LastOrderId)->getIncrementId();`

Comment: now you change the question both output will be same  **000000016**

Comment: Yeah sorry about that.

Comment: So, if I want to load new order What should I do? This will load the previous order won't it ? I am making a payment gateway. When it redirects to the payment gateway It shows the order that was placed before , not the current order that is in the cart.

Comment: @ChetandeepSingh before the redirection to payment page order is already created this will must give you correct result.

Comment: No, It is not, I am using the two lines in the question to create the order, It is loading previous order not the current order

Comment: @ChetandeepSingh this  two line code is not creating any order you are loading the order data with order increment id. This code is also used by magneto in on order success page to get order information.

Comment: Then how to get the current order ?

Comment: @ChetandeepSingh when you redirect to payment page the order is created you can check it admin order there will be new order so last order you are using the correct code.

Comment: How to get that new order then ?

Comment: Hi, Can you answer this question please ? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/200490/how-to-get-the-current-order-details