# How to get the current order details?

Tags: magento2, sales-order, payment-gateway

I am creating a Payment Gateway and I use SetOrder to load into our api,

```
$orderIncrementId = $this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder()->getIncrementId();
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $this->_orderFactory->create()->loadByIncrementId($orderIncrementId);
api = $objectManager->create('Magento\MyModule\Model\Api\Transact')->setConfig($this->getConfig());
        $api->setOrderId()
            ->setCurrencyCode($order->getBaseCurrencyCode())
            ->setOrder($order)
            ->setConfig($this->_scopeConfig->getValue('payment/mymodule_gateway'))
            ->setReturnUrl($this->_urlBuilder->getUrl('mymodule/checkout/response'));
```

Because of this I am getting the previous order not the order that is currently in the cart.

I want the current order. How to get the current order?

Update:

```
<?php

namespace Magento\mymodulePG\Model;

use Magento\mymodulePG\Model\Api\Transact as TransactAPI;
use Magento\mymodulePG\Model\Api\Request as RequestAPI;
use Magento\mymodulePG\Model\Api\Update as UpdateAPI;
use Magento\mymodulePG\Model\Api\Check as CheckAPI;
use \Magento\mymodulePG\Helper\Checksum;

class Transact extends \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod {

    const CODE = 'mymodule_gateway';

    /* protected $_canAuthorize            = true; */
    protected $_code                    = self::CODE;
    protected $_canCapture              = true;
    protected $_isInitializeNeeded      = true;
    protected $_canUseInternal          = false;
    protected $_canUseForMultishipping  = false;
    protected $_canVoid                 = true;
    protected $_canRefund               = true;


    protected $_scopeConfig;

    protected $_exception;

    protected $_checkoutSession;
    protected $_transactionRepository;
    protected $_orderFactory;

    protected $_transactionBuilder;
    protected $_payment;


    protected $_urlBuilder;
    protected $_order;


    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $_cacheFrontendPool;
    protected $_cacheTypeList;

    public function __construct(
      \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
      \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedExceptionFactory $exception,
      \Magento\Sales\Api\TransactionRepositoryInterface $transactionRepository,
      \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Transaction\BuilderInterface $transactionBuilder,
      \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory,
      \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
      \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
      \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
      \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesFactory $extensionFactory,
      \Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValueFactory $customAttributeFactory,
      \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentData,
      \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
      \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Logger $logger, 
      \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
      \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList,
      \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool $cacheFrontendPool,
      \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
      \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
      array $data = []
    ) {
      $this->_urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
      $this->_exception = $exception;
      $this->_transactionRepository = $transactionRepository;
      $this->_transactionBuilder = $transactionBuilder;
      $this->_orderFactory = $orderFactory;
      $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
      $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
      $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;

      parent::__construct(
          $context,
          $registry,
          $extensionFactory,
          $customAttributeFactory,
          $paymentData,
          $scopeConfig,
          $logger,
          $resource,
          $resourceCollection,
          $data
      );
    }

    /**
     * Url to which the post form will be submitted
     * and the user will be redirected
     * @param String Url
     */


    public function getPostForm() {

        $fields = self::getCheckoutFormFields();
        $form = '<form id="mymodule_checkout" method="POST" action="' . self::getmymoduleTransactAction() . '">';
        foreach($fields as $key => $value) {
            if ($key == 'returnUrl') {
        $form .= '<input type="hidden" name="'.$key.'" value="'.\Magento\mymodulePG\Helper\Checksum::sanitizedURL($value).'" />'."\n";
      } else {
        $form .= '<input type="hidden" name="'.$key.'" value="'.\Magento\mymodulePG\Helper\Checksum::sanitizedParam($value).'" />'."\n";
      }
        }
        $form .= '</form>';
        $html = '<html><body>';
        //$html .= $this->__('You will be redirected to the mymodule website in a few seconds.');
        $html .= $form;
        $html.= '<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("mymodule_checkout").submit();</script>';
        $html.= '</body></html>';
        return $html;

    }
    public function getmymoduleTransactAction() 
    {
        return 'url';
    }



    /**
     * Url for calling the update api
     * @param String Url
     */
    public function getmymoduleUpdateApiUrl() 
    {
        return 'url';
    }

    /**
     * Instantiate state and set it to state object
     * @param string $paymentAction
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DataObject
     */
    public function initialize($paymentAction, $stateObject)
    {
        $state = Order::STATE_PENDING_PAYMENT;
        $stateObject->setState($state);
        $stateObject->setStatus('pending_payment');
        $stateObject->setIsNotified(false);
    }

    /**
     * Method to get the form fields with the relevant fields filled in
     * @return Array of form fields in the name=>value form 
     */
    public function getCheckoutFormFields()
    {   

        $orderIncrementId = $this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder()->getIncrementId();
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $order = $this->_orderFactory->create()->loadByIncrementId($orderIncrementId);
        // var_dump($orderIncrementId->getCurrentValue()); die();
        $this->_checkoutSession->setOrderId($orderIncrementId);
        $api = $objectManager->create('Magento\mymodulePG\Model\Api\Transact')->setConfig($this->getConfig());

        //$corder = $this->orderDetails(\Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface $payment);
        $api->setOrderId()
            ->setCurrencyCode($order->getBaseCurrencyCode())
            ->setOrder($order)
            ->setConfig($this->_scopeConfig->getValue('payment/mymodule_gateway'))
            ->setReturnUrl($this->_urlBuilder->getUrl('mymodulepg/checkout/response'));
        // export address
        var_dump($this->orderDetails(\Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface $payment)->getData()); die();
        $isOrderVirtual = $order->getIsVirtual();
        //var_dump( $this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder()->getIncrementId()); die();
        $api->setBillingAddress($order->getBillingAddress());
        if ($isOrderVirtual) {
            $api->setNoShipping(true);
        } elseif ($order->getShippingAddress()) {
            $api->setShippingAddress($order->getShippingAddress());
        }
        // add cart totals and line items
        $result = $api->getRequestFields();


        $this->_checkoutSession->setmymoduleChecksum($api->getmymoduleChecksum());
        return $result;
    }  

    public function mymoduleSuccessOrderState() 
    {
        $order_status = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('payment/mymodule_gateway/order_status');
        switch ($order_status) {
        case "processing":
            $state = \Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PROCESSING;
            break;
        case "complete":
            $state = \Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_COMPLETE;
            break;
        case "closed":
            $state = \Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_CLOSED;
            break;
        case "canceled":
            $state = \Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_CANCELED;
            break;
        case "holded":
            $state = \Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_HOLDED;
            break;
        case "pending":
    case "success":             $state = \Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_COMPLETE;
    break;
        default:
            $state = \Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PENDING_PAYMENT;
        }
        return $state;
    }

    public function capture(\Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface $payment, $amount) 
    {
        $order = $payment->getOrder();
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $api = $objectManager->create('Magento\mymodulePG\Model\Api\Update');
        $api->send($order->getIncrementId(), UpdateAPI::$STATUS_SETTLED, 'payment captured');        
        if ($api->getResponseCode() == 196) {
            // Mage::throwException('Online Capture failed. mymodule Update Api responded Response Code: '.$api->getResponseCode() . ' Message: ' . $api->getResponseDescription());
            // Mage::log('mymodule update api failure: orderId: '.$order->getIncrementId() . ', responseCode: ' . $api->getResponseCode(). ', responseDescription: ' . $api->getResponseDescription());
        }
    }

    public function cancel(\Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface $payment) 
    {
        $order = $payment->getOrder();
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $api = $objectManager->create('Magento\mymodulePG\Model\Api\Update');
        $api->send($order->getIncrementId(), UpdateAPI::$STATUS_CANCELLED, 'order cancelled');
    //*****************************************************//
    $order_check = $payment->getOrder();
        $api_check = $objectManager->create('Magento\mymodulePG\Model\Api\Check');
        $api_check->check($order_check->getIncrementId());
    $response_code = $api_check->getResponseCode();
    if(!$response_code == 213 ) // transaction already cancelled by merchant
    {
       if( !in_array($api->getResponseCode(), array(243,230)))
    {
            // Mage::throwException('Request could not be completed since mymodule Update Api responded with update failure. Response Code: '.$api->getResponseCode());
            // Mage::log('mymodule update api failure: orderId: '.$order->getIncrementId() . ', responseCode: ' . $api->getResponseCode(). ', responseDescription: ' . $api->getResponseDescription());
        }}
    }

    public function void(\Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface $payment) {
        $order = $payment->getOrder();
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $api = $objectManager->create('Magento\mymodulePG\Model\Api\Update');
        $api->send($order->getIncrementId(), UpdateAPI::$STATUS_CANCELLED, 'order void');        
        if (!in_array($api->getResponseCode(), array(226, 198, 213,243))) {
            // Mage::throwException('Request could not be completed since mymodule Update Api responded with update failure. Response Code: '.$api->getResponseCode());
            // Mage::log('mymodule update api failure: orderId: '.$order->getIncrementId() . ', responseCode: ' . $api->getResponseCode(). ', responseDescription: ' . $api->getResponseDescription());
        }
    }

    // refund cannot be consumed as there is no api to capture funds
    public function refund(\Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface $payment, $amount) 
    {
        // Mage::log('refund is getting called');
    }

    // call the check transaction api to show the current status
    public function checkStatus(\Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface $payment) 
    {
        $order = $payment->getOrder();
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $api = $objectManager->create('Magento\mymodulePG\Model\Api\Check');
        $api->check($order->getIncrementId());
        $status = $api->getResponseDescription();
        return $status;
    }

    protected function orderDetails(\Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface $payment) 
    {
      $order = $payment->getOrder();
      return $order;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Ideally in Payment.php you can get order details from
>   Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface
>   by getOrder() method

```
 public function getPostForm(\Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface    $payment) {

    $fields = self::getCheckoutFormFields($payment);
}


public function getCheckoutFormFields(\Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface    $payment)
{
     $order = $payment->getOrder(); 
}
```

Please try with this , Also not required to add (\Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface) in constructor.

Comment: I am getting this `syntax error, unexpected '$payment' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ')'`

Comment: Please post full code include file location so i can get more idea.

Comment: edited the question to add the full code

Comment: hi now getting `Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\mymodule\Model\Transact::getCheckoutFormFields() must be an instance of Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface, none given,`

Comment: Updated answer, Please try again and let me know issue.

Comment: if its working don't forgot accept & upvote :)

Comment: It is showing `Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 8 passed to Magento\mymodulePG\Controller\Checkout\Redirect::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface, none given, called in /var/www/html/magento2/generated/code/Magento/mymodulePG/Controller/Checkout/Redirect/Interceptor.php on line 14 and defined in /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Magento/mymodulePG/Controller/Checkout/Redirect.php:15`

Comment: Please clear cache & remove var/generation folder

Comment: getting this now `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:50`

Comment: Sorry no idea ... ideally in Payment.php, you can order details from Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface

Comment: @Yogesh, can we get Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface payment object from order object?